# Get the followers of a list item

Tags: 2013, following

Is it possible to get all the followers of a list item?

I am registering an event receiver and using `ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties)` to get the `SPListItem`. From this, I would like to get all the followers of the item to give them an alert.

From my partial understanding of `SPSocialFollowingManager`, it seems like it only works in the scope of a single `UserProfile`. Is this really the case?